# Low hardware simulation for performance profiling

Tags: performance, profiling

I need to optimize the app I'm working on and I can't get reliable profiling data on my development machine. The app should run on low end ARM hardware on QNX, but from logistic reasons I don't have access to the final hardware for profiling.

I've tried to do profiling on my development machine, but as you can imagine everything is so fast that I can't pin point the slow parts. I've created a Linux virtual machine with reduced memory and CPU cores count, but they are still too fast compared to the final hardware.

Is it possible to reduce the CPU clock speed/ram speed/disk speed in a virtual machine to simulate low performance hardware or is there any other way to get relevant profiling data on my development machine?

Considering the app is processing several gigabytes of data *I assume* disk access is a major bottleneck and limiting disk speed might help

I can use *any* (as in most open source and commercially available) tool/approach that runs on Windows/Linux/MacOS on real or virtual machine.

Comment: Although processing gigabytes of data, your application runs so fast that your profiler doesn't get enough samples to help you? Weird! What language / tools are you using?

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff it gets samples, but the samples from my development PC and are not relevant for the final hardware. 

My development PC has AMD 3950X CPU, PCIE4 M.2 drive and 96GB of RAM. With this system I can't reliably profile if the bottleneck on the final hardware is CPU, memory or disk access.

Comment: It is hard to profile app in so different environment (your dev machine is x86+linux/win, your target is arm+qnx). There are some virtual machines like qemu or bochs, but they are not cycle-accurate. qemu will be slower for simulating arm on x86, bochs is just slow but will only simulate x86. There were cycle-modelling simulators for x86 like ptlsim and MARSSx86; and there is gem5 model with support of arm (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arm-university/arm-gem5-rsk/master/gem5_rsk.pdf). What is your target core and storage device? You can also try profiling on some Raspberry Pi SBCs.

Answer (score 1):

This [URL](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#storage-bandwidth-limit) describes how to limit disk bandwidth on VirtualBox images. You could run a Linux VM on Virtualbox and use this method to limit disk access speeds, turn off Disk Caching using suggestions from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/160185/turn-off-linux-file-cache) answer and profile your application. Alternatively you can download QNX [SDP](https://blackberry.qnx.com/en/sdp7), which comes with the option of a prebuilt x86_64 Virtual Machine image that can be run using VMWare/Virtualbox/qemu

My previous experiences with QNX on armv7 and x86_64 suggest that the devb-sdmmc driver is possibly a bottleneck when working with a lot of big files being read from flash storage. devb-sdmmc and io-blk often require fine tuning of the drivers with proper cache, block, read-ahead size and other parameters helps improve disk access performance.